# Is this the correct way to send a Email? Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I was just wondering if this was the correct way to send a email?

Does everything looks like it should be with a normal email program?

```
import smtplib

login_Info = ["testemailforthis@gmail.com", "Password"]
receivers = ["testemailforthis@gmail.com"]

message = """From: Me
To: People
Subject: Test email

Hi this is a test email :D"""

try:
    email_thing = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    email_thing.ehlo()
    email_thing.starttls()
    email.login(login_Info[0], login_Info[1])
    email_thing.sendmail(login_Info[0], receivers, message)
    email_thing.close()
    print("The email was sent!")
except:
    print("The email was unable to send!")
```

Comment: Have you ran it? Does it work?

Comment: @Celeo Yes I ran one that was very similar to what I posted but I am asking if it looks like it is all correct.

Comment: SO really isn't for code review. But to give you a heads up, you shouldn't `except` all errors and print. When error occurs, no one really knows what is causing the problem and it will be very hard to debug.

Comment: One thing I learned the hard way is that gmail's security features will lock your account after you send maybe 50 emails via smtp. Even if you change the security settings in gmail, it will still lock you out until you re-log in. My advice is not to use gmail to send the emails via smpt.